# Ionic project on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use Ionic on Visual Studio 2017 community, but when I'm just created blank ionic project, CPU overloads,  computer heats up, cooler makes noise. Task manger does not shows anything except VS, but with ending of the task, or just closing of VS, all comes back to normal.

Output shows second:

[image: Output npm WARN]

If someone has same experience would be helpful to get advice.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using the wrong Visual Studio. People seems to use this one on ionic projects.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Also Ionic projects are started from the command line with:

```
ionic start
```